# sinch stop ios from playing music in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, message, spotify, sinch

My app plays spotify music, and it was keep playing music even in background mode.

But after i've installed sinch !, the music stops when the app enters in background mode.

In capabilities i've turned on the `background modes: audio`,voice IP and remote notifications. I tried to kill the sinchservices before entering in background `([self.sinchClient stopListeningOnActiveConnection];
 [self.sinchClient terminate];)`, but it didn't worked.

Any suggestions?

Here's my code

```
-(void)playUsingSession:(SPTSession *)session {
    // Create a new player if needed
    if (self.player == nil) {
        self.player = [[SPTAudioStreamingController alloc] initWithClientId:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].clientID];
    }
    [self.player loginWithSession:session callback:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            return;
        }
        [self initSinchClient:session.canonicalUsername];

        NSURL *trackURI = [NSURL URLWithString:@"spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp"];
        [self.player playURIs:@[ trackURI ] fromIndex:0 callback:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                return;
            }
        }];
    }];
}

- (void)sendMessageToMe{
    NSArray *recipients = @[self.session.canonicalUsername];
    SINOutgoingMessage *message = [SINOutgoingMessage messageWithRecipients:(NSArray *)recipients text:@"test"];
    [self.sinchClient.messageClient sendMessage:message];
}

#pragma mark - SINClientDelegate methods
- (void)clientDidStart:(id<SINClient>)client {
    self.sinchMessageClient = [self.sinchClient messageClient];
    self.sinchMessageClient.delegate =  self;
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendMessageToMe) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

- (void)initSinchClient:(NSString*)userId {
        self.sinchClient = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:SINCH_APPLICATION_KEY
                                         applicationSecret:SINCH_APPLICATION_SECRET
                                           environmentHost:SINCH_ENVIRONMENT_HOST
                                                    userId:userId];
        [self.sinchClient setSupportMessaging:YES];
        [self.sinchClient setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:YES];
        self.sinchClient.delegate = self;
        [self.sinchClient start];
        [self.sinchClient startListeningOnActiveConnection];
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the app is loosing that audiocategory, is there a method in spotify SDK to "retake" audio resources? Does this only happen after a call?

Comment: @cjensen Yes it does happens only after the call. I´ve tried to "mount" sinch before login and start spotify player, but the music stops anyway. :(.

Comment: Can you try and "restart" spotify client